# Select columns and in a jsonb column only return the last element where meets condition

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have table `documents`, I want to select columns foo and bar. And also the column `comments` which is `jsonb`.

But in `comments` I only need the last element that meets condition `"isUser":false`.

```
"select foo, bar, comments from documents 
 where comments @> '[{"isUser":false}]' 
 limit 1 " /*just limit by 1, the latest comment where isUser = false*/
```

This is how the json looks liks inside `comments` column:

```
[{
    "text": "1 sample lorem ipsum",
    "authorId": "0dcd5a36-2778-4fc4-bbc1-112ed61f1362",
    "timestamp": "2018-11-11T08:46:39.608Z",
    "isUser": false
},{
    "text": "2 sample lorem",
    "authorId": "0dcd5a36-2778-4fc4-bbc1-112ed61f1362",
    "timestamp": "2018-11-11T08:46:41.237Z",
    "isUser": true
},{
...]
```

For `comments` I only need the last object in which `"isUser":false`

Comment: Show us some sample of how the json actually looks like and what output you want to see from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `jsonb_array_elements .. WITH ORDINALITY` to get the order

```
select foo, bar, j.comments
from 
  documents cross 
  join lateral jsonb_array_elements(comments) WITH ORDINALITY j(comments, rn)
WHERE 
  (j.comments ->> 'isUser'):: boolean is false
  ORDER BY j.rn DESC LIMIT 1;
```

**EDIT**

> I want it to limit to 1 json object inside the jsonarray in comments

```
select DISTINCT ON ( foo, bar) foo,bar,comments
FROM 
( select d.foo,d.bar,j.comments,j.rn
from 
  documents d cross 
    join lateral jsonb_array_elements(comments) WITH ORDINALITY j(comments, rn)
WHERE 
  (j.comments ->> 'isUser'):: boolean is false
  ) s
  ORDER BY foo,bar,rn desc  ;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2f4a936a8f7f4826290c46aa978ef12f)

Comment: thanks, kinda works when I add the `limit 1` at the end but is not getting the last in json array, is insertion order not warrantied?

Comment: @commonSenseCode : check now.

Comment: Some progress, so I tested inserting more values. Right now this is limiting the main row return (foo, bar, comments), I want it to limit to 1 json object inside the jsonarray in `comments`, not to limit the rows.

Comment: @commonSenseCode : It's basically the TOP 1 per group problem. You may use `DISTINCT ON`.  check edit. Please remember that when you ask a question, your sample data and expected output should reflect the complete requirement.

Comment: Hi Kaushik this is way nearer to what I need, is there a wat to order DESC by field timestamp inside comments. Somehow sometimes it doesn't give the last added comment

Comment: @commonSenseCode : Also note that I have assumed here that foo and  bar to be the distinct columns, but if you have another unique id in the table, you should use that in the `DISTINCT ON`  and matching column(s) in  order by

Comment: @commonSenseCode : Please note that this answers your original question. If you think you found it useful you may accept it. If you have further questions  ask that as a new one. Thanks

Comment: so I'm trying the end orderby:   `ORDER  BY  (rn.comments->>'timestamp')::timestamp DESC` but doesn't work. If you have an idea I appreciate further help