# postgresql: Filter in JSON array

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say we have a table `items` which has columns `name` and `attributes`:

```
CREATE TABLE students (
  name VARCHAR(100),
  attributes JSON
)
```

where attributes is an array of (always equally-structured) JSON documents such as

```
[{"name":"Attribute 1","value":"Value 1"},{"name":"Attribute 2","value":"Value 2"}]
```

I now want to find all students where any attribute value matches something (such as `Foo%`). [Here's a playground example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w9DRUoELG43Z4FdCXtsieo/1).

I realize that this isn't exactly the most straight-forward design, but for now it's what I have to work with, though performance of such a search being categorically terribly inefficient would of course be a valid concern.

Comment: `json[]` never makes sense. It's better to store a "real" JSON array inside a `json` column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That would also be fine. I'll change the questiion to be like that instead.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You may use `json_array_elements`to access the elements and then use ->> json operator to search using some value.

```
select s.*,j from 
  students  s 
   cross join lateral json_array_elements ( attributes ) as j
WHERE j->>'value' like 'Foo%'
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=49ab528bcda69b05f1e2a2eb55610081)

**Edit**

> The problem here now is that the cross join will "duplicate" rows. Is
>   there a better way to avoid this

use `WITH ORDINALITY` to generated id per element and then use `DISTINCT ON` to get the first / last  match per student.

```
select DISTINCT ON (name) s.*,j.attr from 
students  s 
cross join lateral json_array_elements ( attributes ) WITH ORDINALITY as j(attr,id)
WHERE j.attr->>'value' like 'Value%'
ORDER BY name,j.id
```

[**Demo2**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=de5d2fd5c51a6383856980607e9f54fb)

Comment: Thanks! The cross join lateral is what I was missing (and will have to look up).

Comment: The problem here now is that the cross join will "duplicate" rows. Is there a better way to avoid this other than selecting a distinct list of the IDs and putting it into an outer query where I select the actual rows with those IDs?

Comment: @IngoBürk : Not sure what duplicates you are talking about, there's only one row per one  json element in the array. You could use a `DISTINCT ON` based on some `order by` to limit them to highest /lowest per match. You should probably ask another question with the details.

Comment: Yes, it returns one row per one element in the array, but that's not the expected output; the expected output is the students where any element matches (i.e., each student only once). I'm not interested in the matching JSON element, just that at least one matched. I do somewhat consider this part of this question as that is how I phrased the question.

Comment: @IngoBürk : Well, then you could use `GROUP BY ` /`DISTINCT ON` to get aggregate/top element based on an order. See my other answers. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53314861/7998591)  or  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53247711/7998591)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Do you have an example of what this would look like here? The only solution I came up with so far is `SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(student_id) FROM students CROSS JOIN LATERAL …)`. The example you linked to seems to only select what is grouped by and aggregates, but I want the entire student record.

Comment: @IngoBürk : Ok, I edited my answer and added the query. have a look.

Comment: Thanks! Since I do want a different order I had to use a subquery afterall, but I can select it right from the subquery now: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT … CROSS JOIN …) t ORDER BY … LIMIT …`. That seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` function to filter sub json data

```
SELECT s.* FROM
students s 
WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT 1 FROM json_array_elements ( attributes ) as att WHERE att ->> 'value' ILIKE 'Foo%')
```

Comment: in this case, do you don't filter the content of json array "attributes"

Comment: Oh, ok I got it. I was thinking that filtering json array wasn't in need.

Answer (score 1):

I searched a lot for an easier solution for a clean where clauses in Laravel and and couldn't find it, so I came up with bellow idea.

```
SELECT * FROM students where lower(attributes::text) ilike '%"<key>"%"<value>"%'
```

If your parse json properly key and values are all stored in (") double quotes.

Notice I added (") double quotes to kay and value so it matches the exact key and value.